# How to use React forwardRef with react-redux in Class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-forwardref

How can I use `forwardRef` in Class Component with the connect function of `react-redux`?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class ParentComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

render() {
    return <ChildComponent ref={this.myRef} />;
}
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

**Child Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class ChildComponent extends Component {
render() {
    return <TextInput value={'Hi'} ref={??} />;
}
}

export default connect(null, null, null, { forwardRef: true })(ChildComponent);
```

I don't know how to use `React.forwardRef()` in Class Component.

Answer (score 1):

The `connect` function is a Higher Order Component. You can follow the steps here in [forwarding refs in higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components) to understand better how a HOC can forward a ref to a wrapped component.

The gist is that a react ref isn't a prop, it is special like react keys, but you can pass them as props when necessary. `{ forwardRef: true }` option for `connect` will only forward a `ref` to the wrapped component, in this case `ChildComponent`. You instead want to actually "pass" a ref further and attach it to a child component of `ChildComponent`.

1. Create ref in parent component.
2. Pass the ref as a named prop, `forwardedRef`, to child component.
3. (a) Destructure/access the named ref in child component and (b) attach to the inner child component.

Parent Component

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef(); // <-- (1)
  }

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent forwardedRef={this.myRef} />; // <-- (2)
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { forwardedRef } = this.props; // <-- (3a)
    return <TextInput ref={forwardedRef} value={'Hi'} />; // <-- (3b)
  }
}
```

***Note:** Since we aren't attaching a ref to `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` doesn't need it, it is unnecessary to specify `forwardRef: true` in the `connect` HOC config argument given the provided code example.*